# transform sparse matrix to table

Tags: python, pandas, sentiment-analysis

i got my dataset like this
and then i did my tf_idf vectorizer[tf idf code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGrqz.png)
and got this[tf idf result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoInb.png)

but when i want to make it look like a table using pandas, the result are 0 [result when i try to transform with pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wEXp.png)

can u guys help me? :(

i tried using toarray() but the result gone all zero

Answer (score 0):

Use the pandas from_spmatrix, once you're dealing with an sparse matrix.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = ['This is the first document.','This document is the second     document.','And this is the third one.','Is this the first document?']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
# Show the type of X
print(type(X))
# Convert to pandas dataframe
pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(X)
```